# Stanford NLP : Constituency parser in French

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I want to use the Stanford NLP constituency parser in my Python program.
My server is working well.

---

**What I want**
I want to obtain the result that I have when using the server in a web browser :

[image: The result I want]

---

**My code**
Here is my code :

```
from stanfordnlp.server import CoreNLPClient
from nltk.tree import Tree
with CoreNLPClient(annotators=[ 'tokenize','ssplit','pos','parse'],
                   timeout=30000,
                   output_format="json",
                   properties={'tokenize.language' :'fr',
                               'pos.model' : 'edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/french/french.tagger',
                               'parse.model' : 'edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz'}) as client :
    ann = client.annotate(text)

output = ann['sentences'][0]['parse']
parsetree = Tree.fromstring(output)
parsetree.pretty_print()
```

---

**My current result**
My current result is like that :

```
                         ROOT                 
                          |                    
                         SENT                 
    ______________________|________________    
   |           NP                          |  
   |      _____|__________                 |   
   |     |     |          PP               |  
   |     |     |      ____|____            |   
   VN    |     |     |         NP          |  
   |     |     |     |     ____|_______    |   
   V    DET    NC    P   ADV   P  DET  NC PUNC
   |     |     |     |    |    |   |   |   |   
Cherche les enfants  de moins  de  3  ans  .
```

We can see that the structure is not the same ...
Do you have an idea why my result is different ?

Comment: Have you looked at the source for your visualization software? How does it get this tree (presumably it's some kind of API endpoint backed by Python, maybe Java?).

Comment: I am currently looking into it : it is a POST request with a property called pipelineLanguage ... I think my issue is about this part, but pipelineLanguage doesn't seems to be a parameter for CoreNLPClient. I am trying to figure out what this pipelineLanguage property is in my code.

Comment: Great! Then you'll probably be able to answer your own question. I would grep the CoreNLP codebase for every instance of `pipelineLanguage`. You'll probably find where the server handles this request and then can trace from there to find how it invokes the API. I'm assuming that that POST request is to some intermediary server that then queries the API. If not, then take a look at the body of that POST request. If it matches what you get back from the Python client, then you have all the information, but just need to visualize it properly. Look at JS to see how it parses the response

Comment: I looked into the CoreNLP codebase ([link]https://github.com/stanfordnlp/python-stanford-corenlp/blob/master/corenlp/client.py) and there is no instance of pipelineLanguage ... the word pipeline is appearing 4 times but there is no editable parameters. And when I looked at the response of the POST request, the body is different. I am a bit lost : I don't know where to look to solve my issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution :

Here are the basecode that define the pipeline for french :

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties

So the parse model to use in order to have the same result is :

```
parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz
```

Comment: So you meant `parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/frenchSR.beam.ser.gz`? This is the parser used in the link you mentioned.